# How do i show a panel that only receives keyboard inputs?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm currently working on a swing application for a supermarket.
In my current KeyListener when I press the number 1 a panel has to show up and ask the user for input to confirm if he wants to reset a number.
The problem is that the user is only using a [Numpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37svD.jpg) .
I have been trying every combination of JOptionPane but none of them receive a keyboard-only input, it always asks for the "OK" button or "Cancel" to be pressed with a Mouse.
I also thought about the possibility of navigating it with TAB and remapping that key to a 2 or 3 in the Numpad but no avail.
Here is an example of where this would have to be:

```
KeyListener KeyboardEvent= new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyChar() == '1' && panel2.isVisible() == false) {

            /*Here he asks for the return value, if the return value is 1 I have to reset a 
            variable, if not then I just keep going
            */

        }
```

}

To sum up:
Is there an alternative to the option pane that waits and receives a keyboard input and closes after receiving it without pressing anything else?
Thank You.

EDIT: After trying to use a KeyboardFocusManager

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                        .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                                boolean keyHandled = false;
                                if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                                    System.out.println("Entro");
                                    if (e.getKeyCode() == '1') {
                                        Variables.contador = 0;

                                        // Modifico la label del contador
                                        Label_Contador_Chico.setText(Integer.toString(Variables.contador));

                                        // Guarda el numero del contador correspondiente en la bdd
                                        DBConnection.DBInsertar("UPDATE `joy`.`settings` SET `settingscol` = '"
                                                + Integer.toString(Variables.contador)
                                                + "' WHERE (`idsettings` = 'Contador');");
                                        dialog.dispose();
                                        keyHandled = true;
                                    }else if (e.getKeyCode() == '2') {
                                        dialog.dispose();
                                        keyHandled = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                return keyHandled;
                            }
                        });
```

It's working as intended the first time but when I close the JDialog it keeps listening in all the Frame, is there a way to attach it to the JDialog so it gets disposed when I dispose of the Dialog?

EDIT 2:
I tried to implement the new class like this:

```
public class escucha {
    

    public int dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e, JDialog ventana) {
        int numero = 0;
        System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == '1') {

                numero = 1;
            } else if (e.getKeyCode() == '2') {

                numero = 2;
            }
        }
        return numero;
    }

}
```

And they i call it like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "dialog Box");

                // setsize of dialog
                dialog.setSize(450, 70);
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);

                // create a label
                JLabel l = new JLabel("Aprete 1 para aceptar, 2 para cancelar");
                l.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                l.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

                dialog.getContentPane().add(l);
                escucha objeto = new escucha();
                System.out.println(objeto.dispatchKeyEvent(e, dialog));
                
                
                
                
                if (objeto.dispatchKeyEvent(e, dialog) == 1) {
                    Variables.contador = 0;

                    // Modifico la label del contador
                    Label_Contador_Chico.setText(Integer.toString(Variables.contador));

                    // Guarda el numero del contador correspondiente en la bdd
                    DBConnection.DBInsertar("UPDATE `joy`.`settings` SET `settingscol` = '"
                            + Integer.toString(Variables.contador) + "' WHERE (`idsettings` = 'Contador');");
                    dialog.dispose();
                } else {
                    if (objeto.dispatchKeyEvent(e, dialog) == 2) {
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                }
```

But the objeto.dispatchKeyEvent(e, dialog) method always returns 0.
I dont know why its not entering into: `if (e.getKeyCode() == '1')`.

Comment: Use a `modal JDialog`. You can always just invoke `dispose()` on the dialog in your listener code to close the dialog.

Comment: Okay i have been trying to use JDialog but I am having problems with the listener, the actual `addKeyListener` wasn't working so I tried with the KeyboardFocusManager as seen here: [link](https://coderanch.com/t/337136/java/KeyListener-listens-JDialog) but the listener is attached to the frame and not the JDialog: I will update the post with that info

Comment: *is there a way to attach it to the JDialog so it gets disposed when I dispose of the Dialog?* - make the KeyEventDispatch an inner class. Then you create an instance of the class and assign it to a variable. Then you can remove it before you dispose() of the dialog.

Comment: Will try it and Edit it

Comment: The suggestion was to add/remove this new inner class from the KeyboardFocusManager.

Comment: Okey sorry I am new to programming, i will try investigating that, thank you